# solr: boost query will be ignored

Tags: solr

Hello when i execute following query

```
fl=id model label timestamp score uuid&echoParams=all&qf=label^6 content_level_high^5 content_level_middle^2 content_level_less^1&hl.fl=teaser&wt=xml&rows=9&defType=edismax&facet=true&bq=model:"Component"^10 model:"Object"^90 model:"Address"^1 model:"eav_table_54f5d74b4efef9.49994240"^14&debugQuery=on&start=0&q=Fraumünster
```

The same query easier to readable

```
defType=edismax
fl=id model label timestamp score uuid
qf=label^6 content_level_high^5 content_level_middle^2 content_level_less^1
bq=model:"Component"^10 model:"Object"^90 model:"Address"^1 model:"eav_table_54f5d74b4efef9.49994240"^14
q=Fraumünster
start=0
rows=9
wt=xml
facet=true
echoParams=all
debugQuery=on
hl.fl=teaser
```

to a solr 3.6.2 server it seams that the boost on "model" field will be totaly ignored.

Because all entrys get the same score by having a single hit in "label".
So the order should imho be done by boost query order.

Here a full explain:
http://explain.solr.pl/explains/ipu6qacf

The raw query result:
http://pastebin.com/3uFdd8uw

Solr schema (for solr 5.x):
http://pastebin.com/0pZB5gDt

Solr config:
http://pastebin.com/Kd6W2nYD

The documents to in solr add syntax:
http://pastebin.com/HMBrwAWV

Has anyone an idea what is wrong with the boost query?

Comment: Excellent debug tool on http://explain.solr.pl

Comment: I can just think of trivial errors like: 1. fixed bq params in the query handler 2. field "model" not indexed Can you check these? Can you also provide the "parsedquery" value in the response?

Comment: I add a pastebin with RAW XML query result. The includes "parsedquery". The "model" is indexed i addet this part of schema to question. I am not shure about the fixed bq and how to check this.

Comment: The boost query appears in the parsedquery. So I think, it's no error of the query parser or handler configuration. Sorry. No other idea.

Comment: Have you tried, if searching in the field "model" is possible? e.g. q=model: Component

Comment: Yes it is possible and work as expected.

Comment: The '+' symbols in the parsedQuery are possible wrong (+model:Component^10.0). Can you try, if a single boostquery (just model:Component^10.0) changes anything? If that helps, I would specify each bq as a single request param. Perhaps that will construct the query differently. Unfortunatly I don't have a solr 3.6 instance. I think, that's why no one else has given an answer yet.

Comment: I tryed my query with solr 5.3.1 but got the same result.   &bq=model:Component^10.0&  makes also no differents

Comment: The same result for:  &bq=%2Bmodel:Component^10.0&    parsedquery=(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((content_level_less:fraumun | label:fraumun^6.0 | content_level_high:fraumun^5.0 | content_level_middle:fraumun^2.0)) (+model:Component^10.0))/no_coord

Comment: Hello Mathias: ifyou like to debug further, i addet to comemnt the realted documents

Comment: Now I could reproduce your problem and I found a solution.

Comment: In your last test you put a + Symbol in the query string: bq=%2Bmodel:Component == bq=+model:Component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please specify all boost queries in single parameters:

```
bq=model:"Component"^10&bq=model:"Object"^90&bq=model:"Address"^1&bq=model:"eav_table_54f5d74b4efef9.49994240"^14
```

Then the query is correctly parsed and recognized in the relevance:

+(content_level_less:chang | label:chang^6.0 | content_level_high:chang^5.0 | content_level_middle:chang^2.0) model:Component^10.0 model:Object^90.0 model:Address model:eav_table_54f5d74b4efef9.49994240^14.0

0.1813628 = (MATCH) sum of: 0.13184154 = (MATCH) max of: 0.13184154 = (MATCH) weight(label:chang^6.0 in 4) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 0.13184154 = score(doc=4,freq=3.0), product of: 0.041205455 = queryWeight, product of: 6.0 = boost 1.8472979 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=7) 0.003717633 = queryNorm 3.1996138 = fieldWeight in 4, product of: 1.7320508 = tf(freq=3.0), with freq of: 3.0 = termFreq=3.0 1.8472979 = idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=7) 1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=4) 0.04952125 = (MATCH) weight(model:Component^10.0 in 4) [DefaultSimilarity], result of: 0.04952125 = score(doc=4,freq=1.0), product of: 0.04290709 = queryWeight, product of: 10.0 = boost 1.1541507 = idf(docFreq=5, maxDocs=7) 0.003717633 = queryNorm 1.1541507 = fieldWeight in 4, product of: 1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of: 1.0 = termFreq=1.0 1.1541507 = idf(docFreq=5, maxDocs=7) 1.0 = fieldNorm(doc=4)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks that works fine. Also with solr 3.6.2 Thank you very mutch for you patience